# Creating a Win32 dll in VC++ with CLR enabled but no CRT

Tags: visual-c++, clr, crt

I am trying to create a simple Win32 DLL that contains a function that will return, given the name of a process/app, a list of Window IDs of the app's main window. The most efficient way is to leverage the managed code Process.GetProcessesByName() method. However, while the resulting DLL work in certain machine, it failed to be loaded into memory in other. Turn out the DLL is dynamically linked to a specific version of CRT library (msvcr120.dll in specific). So if the target machine doesn't have the same version of CRT library installed, the DLL won't work.

I have tried to build the DLL by statically linked to the CRT library using the /MT switch but the switch to enable CLR support for the managed code is incompatible with the /MT switch

I have also tried to rid the DLL of CRT library altogether by using the NODEFAULTLIB switch and use just WINAPI calls. While I can build the non-managed portion of the DLL successfully with no dependency on CRT, but when I include the managed porton and turn the /clr switch on, I am getting the following errors:

eze_InstallScriptCA.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)
.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ" (?.cctor@@$$FYMXXZ)

Anyone has suggestion how to create a WIN32 DLL that is version independent of CRT and it is CLR enabled in VC++?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

You can, however, distribute msvcr120.dll along with your application.